# Typings of a return object with computed property names

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to write a function like this one:

```js
function createFunctions(name:string) {
   return {
      [`${name}Sender`]: function Sender() {},
      [`${name}Receiver`]: function Receiver() {},
   }
}
```

The return type of this function is

```js
{
    [x: string]: () => void;
}
```

Is it possible to get the typings here right?  Such that the return type of `createFunctions('Message')` would be:

```js
{ 
   MessageSender: () => void
   MessageReceiver: () => void
}
```

?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjQA8W) meet your needs?  In order for this to work you need your function to be generic in the type of `name`, but due to [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) you still won't get the typings you want automatically.  You need to assert the type somewhere, and it's not 100% clear what the "correct" type is in the face of unions and other things.  Anyway, if the approach(es) in the link works for you I can write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - I need to get "beware unions" tattooed on my forehead. No, wait, then I won't see it very often. Fine, a sticky note on the monitor it is.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yeah, union behavior is probably why ms/TS#13948 hasn't been fixed yet.  The "right" thing to do is distribute across unions in the key type, but then you have to worry about performance because an object with a handful of computed properties can generate huge unions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Please see the warning at the end.)

You can create a mapped type to define the return type of the function:

```typescript
type CreateFunctionsResult<Name extends string> = {
    [key in `${Name}Sender` | `${Name}Receiver`]: () => void;
};
```

Then apply that as the function return type, making the function generic:

```typescript
function createFunctions<Name extends string>(name: Name): CreateFunctionsResult<Name> {
    return {
        [`${name}Sender`]: function Sender() {},
        [`${name}Receiver`]: function Receiver() {},
    } as CreateFunctionsResult<Name>;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221001#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAxArgOwMbAJYD2mAzgEoTHoA2wAPAHKIC20EAHipgCbFTHBw8mAOYA+KAF4oAbwCwAKChKoAbQDWEEFCFQABgBJpjFgF8AyhG4Q4uqAB89h4xBPlsEPADdrugLoAuKAAKAEpJcU8CPC4AbgUTOPkAMyxcQkwobARkNFT8ImIGZlYOSx4+ASExIMxiwOcQwPgkFAwcfJJyShoilnE5RWUEYHQ4DIHlSdUDaVrTCysbAKgU9vSoBa5rUJlMgoIqCAA6KgJhIIAiTesLkJioEwAaBSnlFRm5lzcPbyXA1bSRCg3y82zC0j2JAOx1O5wuIN+t3uTxeyhMUEQvGaOTagM6FGodGcokSJgUCmwBWAUDYkky2VaeXSxEuAFkKMREMIIEiFGwjuziJzudc4KFEgB6CVQAB6AH4+QKOVyIAiwZLpfKFEA)

Unfortunately, I can't avoid that type assertion on the actual object. And [thanks to jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73919699/in-typescript-typings-of-a-return-object-with-computed-property-names/73919777#comment130520080_73919699), I think I understand why: unions.

**Beware**: The above will **won't work correctly** if `Name` is a union:

```typescript
// `prefix` has a union type
const prefix = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "Message" : "SomethingElse";
//    ^? const prefix: "Message" | "SomethingElse"
const x = createFunctions(prefix);
// All four of these exist as far as the type is concerned, but of course `prefix`
// will only be one or the other!
x.MessageSender();
// ^? (property) MessageSender: () => void
x.MessageReceiver();
// ^? (property) MessageReceiver: () => void
x.SomethingElseSender();
// ^? (property) SomethingElseSender: () => void
x.SomethingElseReceiver();
// ^? (property) SomethingElseReceiver: () => void
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20221001#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-AxvCSiDgGaTTOgXOgach7jGEC4jygACN0PyE3tRg6aXSGbow1AAO54KPxzBULRV6BEIc55Px5NwACECjYRz1xANRuucFCTupbpnc-1hogCLBa6gG-ks7MFqttvtEGXq-bR5PZ+tIjtDr3K9D8mdR6AA)